# React Native JSX closing tag issues

Tags: react-native, jsx

I have a React Native project and I am trying to implement MapView. I have it nested in a View tag and for some reason unknown to me, it gives me the following error: "Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for ". Here's the code...

```
<View>
    <Mapview initialRegion={{
        latitude: 40.7127753,
        longitude: -73.989308,
        latitudeDelta: .1,
        longitudeDelta: .1
      }}
      region={props.userLocation}
      style={styles.map}>
        <MapView.Marker coordinate={props.userLocation}/>
    </MapView>
  </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god... the v in the initial MapView is not capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the first `MapView` element it is supposed to be self closing. Add a `/` before the closing tag